# Как заменить в тексте токены значениями из таблицы замен?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Есть таблица `t1` с наименованиями организаций:

| NAME |
| --- |
| ЗАО РОМАШКА |
| РОМАШКА ЗАО |
| ООО ПУПКИ |
| АО ИППОДРОМ |

Хочу убрать из названия организационные правовые формы (АО, ЗАО и тд). Использую примерно следующую конструкцию.

```
select 
    NAME, 
    regexp_replace(NAME, '((^|\s|\W)ЗАО($|\s|\W))|((^|\s|\W)ООО($|\s|\W))|((^|\s|\W)АО($|\s|\W))|((^|\s|\W)ИП($|\s|\W))') as c_name 
from t1
```

Как проделать это, имея справочник замен `t2`

| NAME | REPLACER |
| --- | --- |
| ЗАО | 1 |
| АО | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| ИП | 50 |

То есть, берем первую строку из `t1` и по всем заменам из `t2` прогоняем.

Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Вы же показали куда копать - _берем первую строку из t1 и по всем заменам из t2 прогоняем_. Какие сложности возникли при копании?

Comment: Как это реализовать средствами pl/sql? Рекурсивные запросы погуглить или что?

Comment: Пожалуйста не изменяйте вопрос после того, как вам дали ответ. Просто задайте новый вопрос и сошлитесь на текущий, как на взаимосвязанный.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
select regexp_replace (t1.name, '(^|\W)'||t2.name||'($|\W)', t2.replacer) result
from t1 
join t2 on regexp_like (t1.name, '((^|\W)'||t2.name||'($|\W))')
/
```

Результат (тестовые данные см. ниже):

```
RESULT
----------------
1РОМАШКА
РОМАШКА1
2ИППОДРОМ
```

---

```
create table t1 (name) as
    select trim (column_value) from xmlTable ('
    "ЗАО РОМАШКА",
    "РОМАШКА ЗАО",
    "ООО ПУПКИ",
    "АО ИППОДРОМ"') 
/
create table t2 (name, replacer) as
    select 'ЗАО',   '1'  from dual union all
    select 'АО',    '2'  from dual union all
    select 'ИП',    '50' from dual
/
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею. У меня основная проблема, если в одной записи из t1 попадается несколько совпадений. Например ПАО ГК абвгдейка. Надо заменить и ПАО и ГК